Given a type `ScalarOrList` defined `ScalarOrList[T] = T | list[T]`, static check refuses `input: list[str]` for `arg: ScalarOrList[str | int]`?
I had:
from typing import Optional

type ScalarOrList[T] = T | list[T]


def as_list[T](xs: Optional[ScalarOrList[T]], length: int = 1) -> list[T]:
    if isinstance(xs, Sequence) and not isinstance(xs, str):
        return list(x for x in xs)
    elif xs is not None:
        return [xs for _ in range(length)]
    else:
        return []


def f(xs: ScalarOrList[str | int]):
    print(xs)


only_strs: list[str] = ["hello", "world"]
f(only_strs) # <--- complaint here

But this caused the type checker to complain:
Argument of type "list[str]" cannot be assigned to parameter "xs" of type "ScalarOrList[str | int]" in function "f"
  Type "list[str]" is incompatible with type "ScalarOrList[str | int]"
    "list[str]" is incompatible with "str"
    "list[str]" is incompatible with "int"
    "list[str]" is incompatible with "list[str | int]"
      Type parameter "_T@list" is invariant, but "str" is not the same as "str | int"
      Consider switching from "list" to "Sequence" which is covariant

I tried switching to Sequence, but I ran into confusing type checking issues there too:
from typing import Optional, Sequence

type ScalarOrSequence[T] = T | Sequence[T]


def as_list[T](xs: Optional[ScalarOrSequence[T]], length: int = 1) -> list[T]:
    if isinstance(xs, Sequence) and not isinstance(xs, str):
        return list(x for x in xs)
    elif xs is not None:
        return [xs for _ in range(length)] # <--- complaint here
    else:
        return []

This causes the type checker to complain:
Expression of type "list[object* | str* | str]" is incompatible with return type "list[T@as_list]

Switching to Sequence is actually probably not what I want, because it turns out that there are things that are considered sequences, that I would prefer to consider objects in the context of my usage. For example: str, Enum, etc.

A list[str] is not a list[str | int]. Also, why is as_list here? Did you mean to use it for something?

Questions regarding list's variance have already been asked multiple times. If this question is different, how is it different?

My 2 cents: just omit all typing annotations here. Type annotation is sometimes a very bad idea because they can confuse you and anyone reading your code. Although meant for readability, many times it just have the opposite effect, as in your case. Don't worry about type annotations, just write the function code. What's most important is the functionality, not some annotations.

You are implicitely using the assumption that a list[str] is a list[int | str]. This property would be a covariance property.
Except this is wrong. Lists in python are not covariant. This would be true for tuples or other immutable sequences, but it breaks with mutable structures such as lists.
(the reason it breaks is pretty simple. you can do l.append(0) if l is a list[int | str], but you cannot if it is a list[str])
If you can I recommend you switch to immutable structures, or simplify your type-hinting.
